# Using shared_from_this() in constructor

Tags: c++, memory, shared-ptr

As you know it is not possible to use the std::enable_shared_from_this and shared_from_this() pair from the constructor of an object since a shared_pointer containing the class is not yet in existance. However, I really would like this functionality. I have attempted my own system and it seems to be working OK.

```
namespace kp
{    

template <class T>
void construct_deleter(T *t)
{
  if(!t->_construct_pself)
  {
    t->~T();
  }

  free(t);
}

template <class T, typename... Params>
std::shared_ptr<T> make_shared(Params&&... args)
{
  std::shared_ptr<T> rtn;
  T *t = (T *)calloc(1, sizeof(T));
  t->_construct_pself = &rtn;
  rtn.reset(t, construct_deleter<T>);
  t = new(t) T(std::forward<Params>(args)...);
  t->_construct_pself = NULL;
  t->_construct_self = rtn;

  return rtn;
}

template <class T>
class enable_shared_from_this
{
public:
  std::shared_ptr<T> *_construct_pself;
  std::weak_ptr<T> _construct_self;

  std::shared_ptr<T> shared_from_this()
  {
    if(_construct_pself)
    {
      return *_construct_pself;
    }
    else
    {
      return _construct_self.lock();
    }
  }
};

}
```

Can anyone spot any flaws in this logic? I basically use placement new to assign a pointer to the shared_ptr inside the class before the constructor calls.

As it stands I can use it as so:

```
std::shared_ptr<Employee> emp = kp::make_shared<Employee>("Karsten", 30);
```

and in the Employee constructor:

```
Employee::Employee(std::string name, int age)
{
  Dept::addEmployee(shared_from_this());
}
```

Before I commit this to a relatively large codebase, I would really appreciate some ideas or feedback from you guys.

Thanks!

Comment: You can only create these via your custom `make_shared`; if you try to use any other form of initialization, it will fail at runtime. Just use the standard pattern of providing a static `create()` function that creates an instance, then does any operations requiring `shared_from_this()` before returning it.

Comment: Sorry but there's no way this sort of code passes review in my team. Can't you come up with a more simple and self-documenting design? What is the problem that you are _really_ trying to solve, and why do conventional approaches not satisfy that goal?

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been a while but that might be useful to someone with the same issue : the main problem will happen if you attempt to inherit from a class inheriting your `enable_shared_from_this`.
Especially with this line :

```
t->_construct_pself = &rtn;
```

If you have let's say :

```
class Object : public kp::enable_shared_from_this<Object> {
};

class Component : public Object {
};
```

Then the compiler won't be able to cast `std::shared_ptr<Component>*` to `std::shared_ptr<Object>*` as for the compiler those types are not related even though `Component` inherits `Object`.
The easiest solution I see would be to turn `_construct_pself` to `void*` like so :

```
template <class T>
    class enable_shared_from_this
    {
    public:
        void* _construct_pself{ nullptr };
        std::weak_ptr<T> _construct_self;
        std::shared_ptr<T> shared_from_this() const
        {
            if (_construct_pself)
            {
                return *static_cast<std::shared_ptr<T>*>(_construct_pself);
            }
            else
            {
                return _construct_self.lock();
            }
        }
    };
```

And then do

```
t->_construct_pself = static_cast<void*>(&rtn);
```

It's not very sexy and might make other issues arise but it seems to be working...

[EDIT] There is a slightly better and more "C++" alternative, sorry for not thinking about it right away, just do :

```
t->_construct_pself = reinterpret_cast<decltype(t->_construct_pself)>(&rtn);
```

[EDIT2] Make `shared_from_this` const as it does not change anything in the class

[EDIT3] Found an other issue : If you use a copy constructor via `make_shared` and use `operator=` inside the constructor before `shared_from_this`, `shared_from_this` will return the address of copied object, not of the object's copy. Only solution I see is to define empty copy constructor and assignment operator for `enable_shared_from_this` and explicitly call the copy constructor from inheriting classes everytime needed... Either that or MAKE SURE you NEVER call `operator=` before `shared_from_this` inside your copy constructor.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a semantically problem with using shared_from_this() inside the constructor.
The issue is when an exception is being thrown there is no valid object, but you already have setup a shared pointer to it. e.g.:

```
Employee::Employee(std::string name, int age)
{
    Dept::addEmployee(shared_from_this());
    if (...) throw std::runtime_error("...");
}
```

Now `Dept` will have a pointer to this object, which wasn't successfully created.

Comment: Ah but if we only do the addEmployee at the very end of the constructor and make sure to do a removeEmployee at the very beginning of the destructor, then this would also work for "class Manager : public Employee" inheritance. It would then also ensure that an incomplete Employee / Manager would never be in Dept after the make_shared<T> call.

Comment: I just noticed, your code works a little more unexpected: If an exception is being thrown in the C'tor of Employee, that will force a D'tor call. But the D'tor be called shouldn't if a C'tor throws.

Comment: You are right. Whilst I still need to free the memory, I should have really surrounded the call to the destructor in something like "if(!t->_construct_pself)" or something a bit nicer.

I will fix that now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use of `shared_from_this()` in a constructor should be a code smell, even if it worked, because it is a sign of a possible circular dependency and/or use of a pointer to an incomplete object.

One typically calls `shared_from_this()` to pass a smart pointer to `this` object to another object. Doing this during construction would mean that "this" class depends on another component, which depends on "this" class.

Even in the (arguably) valid use case of an object self-registering at some other component, one would be registering an object that is not yet fully constructed, which is a recipe for problems, as pointed out, for example, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40688540/2279059).

The solution I would recommend is therefore to analyze the code or design and look for possible circular dependencies, then break that cycle.

In the "self-registering object" use case, consider moving the responsibility of registration somewhere else, for example, to the same place where the object is being instantiated. If necessary, use a "create" function or factory rather than direct construction.